# How to get this output using sql query,I have two tables ServayQues1 and ServayQuesAns1

Tags: sql-server

```
select A.QueId,Question,Answer from 
ServayQues1 as S inner join ServayQuesAns1 as A
on S.QueId=A.QueId

 QueId |    Question  | Answer
  ----------------------------
   1    test            Ok 
   1    test            not bad
   1    test            need to be improve
  ----------------------------
```

My expected output is below

```
  QueId   |  Question    |   answer1   |  answer2   |   answer3   
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1          test               Ok          not bad     need to be improve  
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I get this output?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows into columns. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you provide the table structure and some records?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need.

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =  COALESCE(
@PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast([answer] as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast([answer] as varchar)+ ']')
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Answer  from 
 ServayQues1 as S inner join ServayQuesAns1 as A
 on S.QueId=A.QueId) s


DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT A.QueId,Question,Answer 
FROM ServayQuesAns1 A inner join
ServayQues1 q on q.QueId= a.QueId
) AS source
PIVOT
(
MAX([Answer])
FOR [Answer] IN (
  ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
)
) AS PivotTable
'
print @PivotTableSQL

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
```